# Drawing grid in Inkscape in millimeter

Tags: inkscape, grids, pixel

If I try to draw a grid in Inkscape, there are two different options:

1. `Extensions` -> `Render` -> `Grid`
2. `Extensions` -> `Render` -> `Kartesian Grid`

But both of them use pixel-metric(?).

Is it possible to use other metrics (e.g. millimeter).

As a workaround, I converted pixel->millimeter, but it didn't work.
There is always an odd scale factor in the conversion :-(.

Do you have any solution?

Comment: What Inkscape version are you using? I have Inkscape 0.48.4 r9939 (Jan  5 2014) and I don't find any "Extra" menu...

However you're right, there's no option to set such metrics in those extensions. I would suggest to do your grid by hand...

Answer (score 18):

Sadly, menu **Extensions -> Render -> Grids > Grid..**. does only take pixels as the measurement.

So I am pretty sure conversion is the way to do it. I find the easiest, most accurate way to do conversion calculations for Inkscape is to do it in Inkscape.

Use the rectangle tool to draw a rectangle on the canvas, then in the tools control bar for the rectangle tool, change the units to **mm**, and set the rectangle to the value you need (in the picture below, I set it to 5 mm square).

[image]

Now, simply change the units back to **px**, and the width and height should have been converted to the pixel value:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I prefer to use Inkscape's built-in document grid option.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or navigate to 
<kbd>File</kbd>→<kbd>Document Properties</kbd>→<kbd>Grids</kbd>

Select <kbd>Rectangular Grid</kbd> and hit the <kbd>New</kbd> button.

You can then edit the properties (and units) of the created grid in the same dialog.

[image]

Comment: I actually want to have a rendered grid which can be used for further drawings or in in the print out. This grid is only a visual reference. Of course one can use this to create a cm-wise grid, but that's alot of work :).

Comment: @Tik0 You can always just manually convert `mm` to `px` - thus render the grid using the existing extension in pixels at 3.78px per mm (when printing @96dpi)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if the answer is to specific, but since their is no general solution to this problem, I cloned Inkscape and patched the grid functionality.

I'll try to improve my patch, so it will be maybe in a release version one day (so please don't down-vote instantly).
Until then, one has to clone [my repository](https://github.com/tik0/inkscapeGrid) and [build it](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/CompilingUbuntu).

My solution is as follows:

`Extra` -> `Render` -> `Grids` -> `Grid` -> `Divide Selection by Spacing FA`

By using this option, one can use the factor given in "Horizontal/Vertical Spacing" as subdivision factor for the selection.

1. Parameterize the selection in pt/cm/m/in/.. (or whatever)
   [image]
2. Create a grid by `Extra` -> `Render` -> `Grids` -> `Grid`
3. Set a tip at `Divide Selection by Spacing FA`
4. Select how many subdivisions of you selection you want to have
   [image]
5. Et voilà, a grid with 50mm/10=5mm vertical spacing and 50mm/20=2.5mm horizontal spacing

[image]

6. It is also possible, to have an offset in the scale of a subdivision
   [image]
7. The grid is now shifted in x and y direction respectively
   [image]