# Inkscape: How to export the grid to PDF?

Tags: inkscape, grids

When saving an Inkscape graphics as a PDF, I also want to save the grid. How can I do this? If I just export to PDF, the grid is not saved.

Answer (score 3):

One can not export the help grid, one must add a grid like explained here :

[Drawing grid in Inkscape in millimeter](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21611/drawing-grid-in-inkscape-in-millimeter)